Поля класса в другом классе c#
Куда нужно передать поля класса:
class Triangle : FigureAngle
    {
        public double sideA = 0;
        public double sideB = 0;
        public double sideC = 0;

Что нужно передать:
 class FigureNoAngle
    {

        public static double GetRadiusTriangle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC)
        {
            return (sideA * sideB * sideC) / Math.Sqrt((sideA + sideB + sideC) * (sideB + sideC - sideA) * (sideC + sideA - sideB) * (sideA + sideB - sideC));
        }

        public static double LengthCircleTriangle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC)
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(sideA + sideB + sideC);
        }

        public static double GetRadiusSquare(double sideA)
        {
            return sideA / Math.Sqrt(2);

        }

        public static double LengthCircleSquare(double sideA)
        {
            return Math.PI * sideA;
        }

        public static double GetRadiusRhombus(double sideA)
        {
            return sideA / Math.Sqrt(2);

        }

        public static double LengthCircleRhombus(double sideA)
        {
            return Math.PI * sideA;
        }
    }


https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/264178 вот тут много интересной информации

Зависит от сценария использования. Можете сам этот класс передавать аргументами во все эти функции и пользоваться внутри функций его полями. Можете этот класс с полями передать в конструктор вычислительного класса, там запомнить в какое-то поле и дальше вызывать эти функции вообще без параметров и брать поля из запомненного класса. Повторюсь - всё зависит от сценариев, в которых этот вычислительный класс используется. В каких-то сценариях один подход будет лучше, в каких-то другой. А может лучше эти два класса просто в один класс объединить сразу.

Для передачи полей класса Triangle в методы класса FigureNoAngle, можно создать экземпляр класса Triangle, а затем использовать значения его полей в вызовах методов.
using System;

class FigureNoAngle
{
    public static double GetRadiusTriangle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC)
    {
        return (sideA * sideB * sideC) / Math.Sqrt((sideA + sideB + sideC) * (sideB + sideC - sideA) * (sideC + sideA - sideB) * (sideA + sideB - sideC));
    }

    public static double LengthCircleTriangle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(sideA + sideB + sideC);
    }

    public static double GetRadiusSquare(double sideA)
    {
        return sideA / Math.Sqrt(2);
    }

    public static double LengthCircleSquare(double sideA)
    {
        return Math.PI * sideA;
    }

    public static double GetRadiusRhombus(double sideA)
    {
        return sideA / Math.Sqrt(2);
    }

    public static double LengthCircleRhombus(double sideA)
    {
        return Math.PI * sideA;
    }
}

class Triangle : FigureAngle
{
    public double sideA = 0;
    public double sideB = 0;
    public double sideC = 0;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Создаем экземпляр класса Triangle и инициализируем его поля
        Triangle triangle = new Triangle();
        triangle.sideA = 3;
        triangle.sideB = 4;
        triangle.sideC = 5;

        // Используем поля экземпляра triangle в методах класса FigureNoAngle
        double radiusTriangle = FigureNoAngle.GetRadiusTriangle(triangle.sideA, triangle.sideB, triangle.sideC);
        double lengthCircleTriangle = FigureNoAngle.LengthCircleTriangle(triangle.sideA, triangle.sideB, triangle.sideC);
    }
}



А, ну если мы не можем менять класс FigureNoAngle, то да, так. Но вообще передача в методы нескольких однотипных параметров рано или поздно может привести к ошибкам, когда вместо одного параметра будет передан другой и никак это нельзя отследить, никто не отругается. А когда параметром передаётся класс с полями, ошибиться сложнее.

@CrazyElf, Согласна, что использование класса с полями для передачи данных может сделать код более читаемым и уменьшить вероятность ошибок при передаче параметров, помимо этого это еще и создаст гибкость архитектуры и именно поэтому я привела выше ссылку по азам сишарпа

в моем ответе я представила самый простой способ передачи полей класса Triangle в методы класса FigureNoAngle, чтобы ответить на вопрос ТС. Я не нашла дубликат к сожалению

Ну я не с претензией, я как бы дополняю ваш ответ общими рассуждениями. Что конкретно хотел автор вопроса до сих пор не очень понятно. Возможно, он именно ваш вариант и имел в виду.
